# Swift: Change autolayout constraints when keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview, uikeyboard

I am trying to have the bottom of a `UItextView` change constraints when the keyboard is presented so the `UItextView`is "constrained" by the textView.  I have a `UIView` I have named spacer in between the `UItextView` and the bottom layout guide.  I am trying to change the value of the constraint for the spacer to the bottom of the view to the keyboard height.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!    
@IBOutlet weak var spacer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var spacerBottomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AdditionalDetailsVC.keyboardShown(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

and where the magic happens:

```
func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    let info  = notification.userInfo!

    let value: AnyObject = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!

    let rawFrame = value.CGRectValue

    keyboardFrame = view.convertRect(rawFrame, fromView: nil)

    print(keyboardFrame)

    print(spacerBottomLayoutConstraint)

    //Setting text field to bottom of keyboard
    //spacerBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.height

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {

        self.spacerBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = self.keyboardFrame.height

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? I see your code and I see your goal but I don't see a question. (By the way, you do not need to animate; you get automatic animation together with the keyboard.)

Comment: I want the keyboard to push the `UITextView` and keep the buffer of the `UIView` spacer in between.  Right now the text field is behind the keyboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I find it a lot simpler to adjust the bottom content inset of the text view. This code is for a text view that occupies the whole window (so its bottom is the bottom of the screen); a text view that doesn't come down that far would require a little more elementary arithmetic:

```
func keyboardShown(n:NSNotification) {
    let d = n.userInfo!
    var r = (d[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    r = self.textView.convertRect(r, fromView:nil)
    self.textView.contentInset.bottom = r.size.height
    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = r.size.height
}
```

Comment: In Swift 3, `CGRectValue()` is `cgRectValue`

Comment: @JasonMoore In Swift 3, you can cast directly to CGRect and skip the NSValue altogether. Updated version of the code is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift

Comment: Sweet! So `d[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect` for anyone else stumbling across this.

Answer (score 3):

you can try the below code to to change the value of the constraint for the spacer to the bottom of the view to the keyboard height. Put the below code in your ViewController.

```
// MARK: Keyboard Event Notifications

func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    print(notification)
    print(notification.object)

    // Get information about the animation.
    let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

    let rawAnimationCurveValue = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).unsignedLongValue
    let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: rawAnimationCurveValue)

    // Convert the keyboard frame from screen to view coordinates.
    let keyboardScreenBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    let keyboardViewBeginFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenBeginFrame, fromView: view.window)
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenEndFrame, fromView: view.window)
    print(keyboardViewBeginFrame)
    print(keyboardViewEndFrame)

    // Determine how far the keyboard has moved up or down.
    let originDelta = keyboardViewEndFrame.origin.y - keyboardViewBeginFrame.origin.y
    print(originDelta)

    // Adjust the table view's scroll indicator and content insets.
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom -= originDelta
    textView.contentInset.bottom -= originDelta

    print(keyboardViewEndFrame)

    spacerBottomLayoutConstraint?.constant = CGFloat(originDelta)

    // Inform the view that its the layout should be updated.
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];

    // Animate updating the view's layout by calling layoutIfNeeded inside a UIView animation block.
    let animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [animationCurve, .BeginFromCurrentState]
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0, options: animationOptions, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}
```